# How to convert json and show all data in html ? using Javascript and Map

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to loop thought array and show property data.

All code is here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-display-show-json-in-propertlu-format?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Check loop in ts:

```
this.allFilters.push(
  Array.isArray(val.value)
    ? {
        name: val.name,
        value: val.value.map((obj: any) => obj.value).join(" - "),
        displayName: val.displayName,
        displayValue: val.value.map((obj: any) => obj.value).join(" - ")
      }
    : {
        name: val.name,
        value: val.value,
        displayName: val.displayName,
        displayValue: val.displayValue
      }
);
```

and html:

```
  <span
    *ngFor="let filter of allFilters">
    {{ filter.displayName }}: {{ filter.displayValue }}
  </span>
```

Right now result is :

> ```
> First: 2
>
> Second: 2021-04-08 - 2021-04-20
>
> Third: 15
> ```

But what I need is to separate date to dateFrom and dateTo and show like a:

> ```
>  First: 2
>   
>  Second: dateFrom 2021-04-08
>    
>  Second: dateTo:  2021-04-20
>   
>  Third: 15
> ```

OR

> ```
>  First: 2
>   
>  dateFrom: 2021-04-08
>    
>  dateTo:  2021-04-20
>   
>  Third: 15
> ```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to flat your array. I have edited the "recieveMessage" function you are using in the code you linked.

```
recieveMessage(val) {
    if(Array.isArray(val.value)){  
      val.value.forEach(child => this.allFilters.push({
        name: val.name,
        value: child.value,
        displayName: val.displayName + ' ' + child.name,
        displayValue: child.value
      }))
    } else {
      this.allFilters.push({
        name: val.name,
        value: val.value,
        displayName: val.displayName,
        displayValue: val.displayValue
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: this is good but all my array not good. I missed my displayName f0r if val.value is array..

Comment: I need to format name and value by displayValue and displayName..

Comment: If this is not what you were trying to do, please edit your question

Comment: Just need to convert displayValue i change small displayName

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-display-show-json-in-propertlu-format-2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Check this. I need to convert Third AccountPriorityIds: 3 instead 3 and 2 to Medium and Hard